# Iterate to change HTML name fields with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I iterate over the following HTML using Javascript in order to add a 1 to all the `name` fields. For example, "account" would become "account1", etc. I cloned this row from a table, and would like to be able to distinguish between the fields of the two.

```
<td>
    <select name="account">…</select>
</td>
<td>
    <span>
        "$ "<input type="text" name="debit" placeholder="100">
    </span>
</td>
<td>
    <span>
        "$ "<input type="text" name="credit" placeholder="100">
    </span>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="reference">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="notes">
</td>
<td>
    <select name="account">...</select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is use `querySelectorAll` to get your elements inside your table, then use a loop and change their names:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable [name]")
inputs.forEach(function(input){
    input.name += + "1";
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/zjpfub35/1/)

Comment: This worked great, except for an item `<td><select name="account">...</select></td>`. I probably should have included that one in my original question. (Also, I am not selecting all elements in the table, only of a certain row which has `id=entryLine1').

Comment: Switched the `#myTable input` to `#myTable [name]`. Works great!

Comment: @cpage Yes sorry about that, re-read the question and changed my answer slightly. I didn't notice your `select` element initially.

Comment: And I am using, `input.name = input.name.replace(/\d+/g, '') + row_count` to prevent "account2" from being "account12".

Answer (score 0):

`var all =document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++){
    if(all[i].name){`
`all[i].name+=1;`
`}`
`}`

Try this.* will give you all elements in the page.